# Making a link in top bar full height

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to place some buttons in my top bar where you can choose the display language. Those buttons should have full height in the top bar like the other buttons:

[image]

But for some reason I can't get those buttons to full height:
[image]

Here is a fiddle with my html and css setup: http://jsfiddle.net/gLgwm/1/

I tried using the following CSS which does not work:

```
#CtlLanguageSelection,
#CtlLanguageSelection a {
    line-height: 35px !important;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Also tried setting `min-height` and `height` to `100%` and `35px`, did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
#CtlLanguageSelection a {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If we set them to `height: 100%;` and give them `display: inline-block` it will work just fine.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/gLgwm/2/)

---

**Note:** If you don't want that little gap between them (caused by `inline-block`) you can do this:

```
<a id="CtlChangeLanguageDE">de</a><a id="CtlChangeLanguageEN">en</a>
```

Just a little trick to sort it, there are many other ways so you can look them up if needed.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/gLgwm/5/)

Comment: Thanks, it was the `inline-block` that was missing here.

Answer (score 3):

The `a` is an inline element, so it takes much space as the text. Make it an `inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/gLgwm/4/

```
#CtlLanguageSelection a {
    line-height: 35px !important;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```